# vim search pattern for a piece of text line yanked in visual mode

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying search a part of some line  which is yanked under visual mode.

What's the quickest way to do it in VIM? For exmaple,

```
Hello, #{1} world.
```

I press <kbd>v</kbd> enter visual mode and select `llo, #{1} wor` at the line 1. Then I yanked the selected text by pressing <kbd>y</kbd>, and then, I am trying to search for the selected text by pressing <kbd>/</kbd>. That leads to the following questions:

A: How to past a yanked text when I am in search mode?

B: How to avoid the work of escaping characters for a search pattern?

Comment: Corrected the title to *visual* mode (was *virtual* before)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've overriden [the star command for the visual mode](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/v_star.vim) (NB: it requires one file from lh-vim-lib). It answers your need:

1. select in visual mode
2. press <kbd>*</kbd>/<kbd>#</kbd>
3. continue searching with <kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I copied the function lh#visual#selection into v_star.vim. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

A:

<kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>.

B:

In addition to the <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> trick, there's also <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd>, which lets you type in an expression to be evaluated and expands to the result.

> <kbd>/</kbd> (now the prompt looks like `/`)
>   <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> (now the prompt looks like `=`)
>   `escape(@0, '\^$*.~[')` <kbd>Enter</kbd> (now the prompt looks like `/llo, #{1} wor`)
>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note that `@reg` means "the contents of register `reg`", and register `0` is the the last yank or delete.  I *think* that escapes all the characters which are special in vi regexps… in any case, you would probably prefer to make a mapping than to type that all in.

Comment: If I yank entire line, i have to delete `^M` or `^@` from the end before searching.

Answer (score 6):

When you yank some text (and specify no register to yank it into), it goes to register 0. So, if you want to search for that yanked text, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to get into normal mode and then

```
/CTRL-r0
```

(i.e. press <kbd>/</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>0</kbd>) to pull the content of register 0 into the search pattern.

Some notes:

- To search for other patterns stored in other registers, you could type [`:reg`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:reg) and watch the register contents before deciding which register content to use for your search.
- To yank into a different register than 0 (e.g. 2), you could type `"2y` ([:he v_y](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#v_y)).
- To search for the selected text directly, you could use the mapping described [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-search) which enables you to simply press <kbd>X</kbd> (uppercase character `X`) while in visual mode to search for that text.
- For searching in general, [this vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/) gives you an introduction to the very powerful command line window with the history of searches (discovered it two weeks ago and absolutely love it!).